# In Ansible, is there a way to pass multiple dictionaries into a with_dict task loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, yaml, ansible

I'm trying to feed multiple dictionaries into with_dict in a task loop.

## vars/users.yml file

```
---
server_admins:
  admin1: comment="Dark Helmet" uid=10000 state=present
  admin2: comment="Princess Vespa" uid=10001 state=present

developers:
  dev1: comment="Prince Valium" uid=2000 state=present
```

## group_vars/webservers.yml

```
---
ssh_users:
  - "{{ server_admins }}"
  - "{{ developers }}"
```

## tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: create users
  user: name={{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}
  with_dict: "{{ ssh_users }}"
```

If I define only one dictionary in {{ ssh_users }} the task runs as expected.  But when I add a second dictionary, I get "with_dict expects a dict".  Apparently it didn't expect two of them!

So far, my workaround has been to create a new role for every group of users, but that is getting out of hand, and just doesn't seem like a good solution, as I'm duplicating the same logic in every role.

Any ideas on how to pass or concatenate multiple dictionaries into with_dict, or structure the data in a way that the task loop can handle; all while still keeping it in a single role?

Comment: you are passing a list of lists of dicts; one solution would be merging the lists using `set_fact: ssh_users:  "{{ developers + server_admins }}"`; another would convert the single user from a dict to an hash (`name='admin1' comment=''...`) and just use with_items.

Comment: The "+" operator is not supported on dictionaries unfortunately.  Also, I have many more users and groups than what are listed here.  I just wrote a simplified version of my role to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

From Ansible 2.0 there is a Jinja filter, [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), for this:

```
  ---
  - name: create users
    user: name={{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}
    with_dict: "{{ server_admins | combine(developers) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example on the combine filter.  However, it's not quite what I was looking for.  The purpose is to make the task reusable, and this solution assumes that I will always be using the same dictionaries, or always have a set amount of dictionaries to pass.  I'll experiment with combine() in group_vars and see if I can get the behavior I'm looking for.